# Coldfusion with BIRT report get parameter DATEFROMSO and DATETOSO and print in excel xls file

Tags: eclipse, birt, coldfusion-11

I have code below in Coldfusion 11 frontend to get parameter DATEFROMSO and DATETOSO at BIRT report.
Please add/adjust the code below to able to get parameter and print record in excel.

```
            <cfset userid = #session.userid#>
            <cfset reportname = "test1.rptdesign">
            <cfset reportparam = reportParameter.getReportParameter("SO_report_xls")>
            <cfset filetype = "xls">
            <cfset downloadPath = SO_Report_excel>

            <cfset printBirt.print(#userid#,#reportname#,#filetype#,#reportparam#,#form#,#fid#,#downloadPath#)>
            <cfoutput>
                <script language="javascript">
                    var filename = '#file['rptfile']#';
                    var downloadPath = '#urlencodedformat(downloadPath)#';
                    var fn = urlencode(filename);
                    window.open('cflib/download_birt_xls.cfm?downloadPath='+downloadPath+'&filename='+fn);
                </script>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfif>
```

I want excel xls file got record from parameter input at Coldfusion frontend function page.